# Вывести все элементы из раздела

Tags: php, битрикс

Иерархия такая: `каталог/раздел1/раздел2/раздел3/элемент`, мне нужно получить массив всех элементов, которые содержаться в `разделе 2`. Вот код:

```
  <?php
    $IBLOCK_ID    = 4;
    $arFilter    = Array(
          'IBLOCK_ID'=>$IBLOCK_ID, 
          'GLOBAL_ACTIVE'=>'Y',
         'SECTION_ID'=>48);
    $obSection    = CIBlockSection::GetTreeList($arFilter);

    while($arResult = $obSection->GetNext()){
       for($i=0;$i<=($arResult['DEPTH_LEVEL']-2);$i++)

          echo $arResult['ID'].'<br>';

    $arSel = Array("ID", "NAME", );
    $arFil = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$IBLOCK_ID,'SECTION_ID'=>$arResult['ID']);
    $arRes = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFil, false, Array())->Fetch();
    print_r ($arRes[NAME]);

    }
```

он выводит последние элементы из всех разделов, цифры - это ID разделов:

```
59
Брелоки для ключей BERLINGO, маленькие, размер 50*20, A260160
60
Корректирующая жидкость+разбавитель Berlingo, 2*20мл, KR-230/25161
61
Клей "Момент 88" особопрочный 30г.62
62
Диспенсер для клейкой ленты 50мм К-20
```

Наверное, нужно как-то зациклить, чтобы он все элементы выводил, например:

```
61
КЛЕЙ
Еще клей
Очень клей
62
Жидкость
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена циклом

> `$rsRes = CIBlockElement::GetList(); while ($arRes =
>   $rsRes->GetNext()) {    ... }

`
 Но вместо скрипта вывел всё компонентом "Элементы раздела", который полностью подходит под мои нужды.